# Finding minimal spanning tree of a graph using Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, interview-questions, graph

I am doing some practice interview questions for class, one of the questions is:

> Given an undirected graph G, find the minimum spanning tree. Function should take in and output an adjacency list.

Here is the code that I have which works using Kruskal's algorithm:

```
### Question 3 main function and helper functions.
# Within code v = vertice, r = root, e = edge, u = union, m = make, f = find.

# Global Variables for simplifying code.
parent = dict()
rank = dict()

# Find vertices.
def f(v):
    if parent[v] != v:
        parent[v] = f(parent[v])
    return parent[v]

# Make vertices.
def m(v):
    parent[v] = v
    rank[v] = 0

# Creates union between vertices.
def u(v1, v2):
    r1 = f(v1)
    r2 = f(v2)
    if r1 != r2:
        if rank[r1] > rank[r2]:
            parent[r2] = r1
        else:
            parent[r1] = r2
            if rank[r1] == rank[r2]: rank[r2] += 1

# Main Function.
def Question3(G):
    for v in G['vertices']:
        m(v)

    edges = list(G['edges'])
    MST = set()

    for e in edges:
        v1, v2, weight = e
        if f(v1) != f(v2):
            u(v1, v2)
            MST.add(e)
    return MST

G = {
    'vertices': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'edges': set([
        (1, 6, 5),
        (3, 5, 2),
        (5, 4, 9),
        (4, 2, 3),
        (1, 1, 8),
        (0, 2, 1),
        (2, 3, 6),
        (2, 5, 4),
        (2, 4, 9),
        (2, 1, 7),
        ])
    }

print "Minimum Spanning Tree of G:"
print Question3(G)

# Expected Output.
# Minimum Spanning Tree of G:
# set([(1, 6, 5), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 4), (2, 1, 7), (2, 3, 6), (0, 2, 1)])
print """---End Question 3---
"""
```

Are there any unnecessary bits of code in my solution and/or is there a more efficient way I could be going about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two comments already imparted a negative impression of the code — something you definitely don't want to do in an interview.

> ```
> # Within code v = vertice, r = root, e = edge, u = union, m = make, f = find.
>
> # Global Variables for simplifying code.
> ```

The first comment indicates that your function names are horrible.  The second comment indicates that you don't know how to use variables with the correct scope.

---

> ```
> G = {
>     'vertices': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
>     'edges': set([
>         (1, 6, 5),
>         (3, 5, 2),
>         …,
>         (2, 1, 7),
>         ])
>     }
> ```

Specifying the `vertices` is redundant, right?  All of the relevant vertices should already be mentioned as one of the endpoints of an edge.  (And if that is not the case, then you have a lone disconnected vertex, and it would be impossible to make a spanning tree.  Such is the case, in fact, with vertex 7 in your example.)

Furthermore, your `Question3()` function returns a graph as a set of edges.  It would also make sense that it accepts a graph as a set of edges.

The `Question3` function should look more like this:

```
def kruskal_mst(graph_edges):
    vertex_parents = {
        v: v for v in itertools.chain(*[(v1, v2) for v1, v2, w in edges])
    }
    vertex_ranks = {v: 0 for v in vertex_parents}

    mst = set()
    for e in edges:
        v1, v2, weight = e
        if find(v1, vertex_parents) != find(v2, vertex_parents):
            union(v1, v2, vertex_parents, vertex_ranks)
            mst.add(e)
    return mst

print kruskal_mst([
    (1, 6, 5),
    (3, 5, 2),
    (5, 4, 9),
    …,
    (2, 1, 7)
])
```

---

Your code ignores edge weights completely.  (Note that your solution uses the `(2, 4, 9)` edge rather than the lower-cost `(4, 2, 3)` edge.  Also, to connect vertex 3 into the MST, it uses the `(2, 3, 6)` edge rather than `(3, 5, 2)`.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I appreciate it. One of the requirements for the question is that the smallest possible edge weight is used for the MST. So it looks like I'm not done quite yet.